# Terraform: what's the difference between "tags" and "tags_all"?

Tags: terraform

After upgrading terraform to `3.64.2`, even though I haven't changed any code, `terraform plan` reminds me that it will replace `tag` with `tag_all`. what's the difference between `tags` and `tags_all`?

```
~ resource "aws_lb_listener" "frontend_http_tcp" {
        id                = "xxxxx"
      ~ tags              = {
          - "environment" = "production" -> null
          - "purpose"     = "onboarding-integration" -> null
          - "terraform"   = "true" -> null
        }
      ~ tags_all          = {
          - "environment" = "production"
          - "purpose"     = "onboarding-integration"
          - "terraform"   = "true"
        } -> (known after apply)
        # (4 unchanged attributes hidden)

        # (1 unchanged block hidden)
    }
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Terraform, you can define tags in top-level. `tags_all` is basically `individual resource tags` + `top level tags`

For example;

```
# Terraform 0.12 and later syntax
provider "aws" {
  # ... other configuration ...
  default_tags {
    tags = {
      Environment = "Production"
      Owner       = "Ops"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc" "example" {
  # ... other configuration ...

  # This configuration by default will internally combine tags defined
  # within the provider configuration block and those defined here
  tags = {
    Name = "MyVPC"
  }
}
```

In above example; `tags_all` will be

```
tags_all = {
  Name = "MyVPC"
  Environment = "Production"
  Owner       = "Ops"
     }
```

while tag is

```
tags = {
    Name = "MyVPC"
  }
```

Reference = https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/resource-tagging

Comment: As of version 3.38.0 of the Terraform AWS Provider, the Terraform Configuration language also enables provider-level tagging. [Terraform Doc: Propagating Tags to All Resources](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/resource-tagging#propagating-tags-to-all-resources)

Comment: ```provider "aws" {
  default_tags {
    tags = {
...``` is exactly what I'd done and it shows `tags_all` being added every time plan is run. I don't understand why this is so.

Comment: It appears in my case this was a bug fixed in Terraform 1.4.6 (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/18311#issuecomment-1544330448).

Comment: So you mean that if we replace `tags` with `tags_all` for the `aws_vpc.example` resource, then that resource's tags will only be `Name=MyVPC`, without the `Environment` and `Owner` tags?

Comment: why are  only `tags_all` documented as output attributes?